# Where can I find the upper bound price for checked-in luggage for Sky Airline when purchased at the airport counter?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, check-in, fees-and-charges

Where can I find the upper bound price for checked-in luggage for Sky Airline when purchased at the airport counter?

https://www.skyairline.com/english/price-list ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191021181639/https://www.skyairline.com/english/price-list)) just gives a lower bound (e.g., "from 38 USD" for the first baggage):

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Sky and asked? https://www.skyairline.com/english/forms/contact

Comment: @David yes,  ~4 days ago, no reply yet.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the page it says:

> Important: Prices may vary due to time of purchase and route flown. The earlier you buy, the more you’ll save!

Therefore, you can’t find the specific upper bound price unless you specify the route.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. Given the route, is there any way to find the upper bound without going through customer service overhead?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt what is the route in question?

Comment: Flight number: sky h2 5062 (from Alejandro Velasco Astete Airport CUZ in Cusco, Peru to Jorge Chávez International Airport LIM in Lima, Peru)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt not sure, I think you might need to send an email/look at your booking page. I would send an email for you but don’t want to put my passport